# Android how to fill a relative layout inside scroll view to full screen

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

i can't fill my relative layout on full screen. when a make another layout for example in bottom, he will just appear after the last layout.
this is my code

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".android_app_activity.EspacePersonnelActivity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ep_background"
    android:id="@+id/espacePersonnelLayout"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >...
```

Answer (score 2):

Always Keep the height of the child of scrollview must be wrap_content. To fill the entire screen you can use the fillViewport attribute of the scroll view. Below is a working example -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jeshtamsru.tntrains.DashboarsActivity">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                 <Button
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:width="300dp"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
           </RelativeLayout>
          <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:width="300sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="chennai to coimbatore"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's normal , a scrollview - that can only have one child- take all the screen space , so everything you will add will be shown in the end .